# GWT: How to change root (?) panel panel type?

Tags: gwt, panel

It is said here http://code.google.com/intl/ru-RU/webtoolkit/tools/gwtdesigner/quick_start.html

that one should "Choose an appropriate panel type for" one's UI.

How this can be accomplished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main panel is always RootPanel, which can be retrieved by RootPanel.get("");

What they are trying to say in the quick start guide is you should choose a panel to add to the RootPanel and start adding widgets in there.

Answer (score 2):

It all depends on your application layout. There is one RootPanel and you keep adding more panels and Widgets into it.

You can read about different panels at:
http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiPanels.html

> Panels in GWT are much like their layout counterparts in other user
>   interface libraries. The main difference is that GWT panels use HTML
>   elements to lay out their child widgets. Panels contain widgets and
>   other panels. They are used to define the layout of the user interface
>   in the browser.

In GWT Designer choose Panel from Layouts and then you drop other child widgets inside (Buttons, Labels, etc).